# Call method with assembly loaded from GAC

Tags: c#, gac

I am trying to call the `Save` method from a `System.Drawing.Image` object, after loading the assembly from the GAC:

```
_drawingAssembly = Assembly.Load
                    ("System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");

_drawingAssembly.GetType("Image").GetMethod("Save").Invoke(myImageObject, new object[] { path });
```

But it's not working. I can't even get the type for some reason; this returns null:

```
var t = _drawingAssembly.GetType("Image"); // null
```

Comment: You need to have fully qualified name of class while calling `GetType` might be `_drawingAssembly.GetType("System.Drawing.Image")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full type name `System.Drawing.Image` as indicated by the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: He'll also need to specify which overload of `Image.Save` he wants from `GetMethod`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx